# How to I redirect (hyperlink) to a server on my site? (:3000)

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, server, href

i am trying to use a hyperlink to redirect people to a game server on my site with the press of a button, but `href="http://mywebsite.net:3000"` does not work.

If i go to the url directly in a new tab, it works, so i know it's not the site that is not working.

When I press the button, the screen does not change at all. The button just doesn't do anything.

I am using node.js and socket.io for my game.

(Server port 3000)

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the entirety of your HTML. There's no reason that code wouldn't work, unless you're not using an anchor element (`<a>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `<button>` nor `<input type="button">` has a property `href`...

Use `<a href="...">` instead. You can style it as a button with corresponding CSS later on.

Another approach would be creating a form with a button of type `submit` inside and putting an `action` property on a form; however this is just an overhead.

Comment: Oh duh.. Thanks bro, i just used onclick="location.href='etc.'"